# When do we use "any" with countable nouns?

Tags: grammaticality

I was reading these questions and I noticed that in one of them, "any" is used with a **singular** countable noun. And in the other one "any" is used with a **plural** countable noun.

I wanted to know why that is ?

Comment: You should add links to the questions you're referring to.

Comment: Can you give any examples?

Answer (score 5):

It depends which kind of *any* you are talking about.

The more common *any* is a [negative polarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarity_item) equivalent of *some*. Like *some*, it is used with a plural or an uncountable:

> I have some books, some wine.

> Do you have any books, any wine?

But we would not normally say

> ? I have some book.

or

> ? Do you have any book?

But there is a second use of *any* which is not a negative polarity item, and is used with countables, singular or plural; it means something like *I don't care which*.

> You can choose any book / any books.

If you use it with an uncountable, it will be like using "a" with the uncountable, and designate a kind or sort:

> You can choose any wine.

means "any kind of wine".

Comment: The second "free choice" _any_ isn't a Negative Polarity Item, but it **is** a Possible Polarity Item. I.e, it must be in the scope of a diamond/possible-category modal, like _may_ or _can_. None of those 2nd-type _any_'s are grammatical without the modal; e.g *_He chose any book there_. That could be grammatical if it referred to a repeated choice, as in a stage trick (with an implied _would_ modal), but not if it referred to one event of choosing a book.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification @JohnLawler: I wasn't aware of that category of polarity, but it makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Negatives, quantifiers, and modals all have "fields" or "scopes", and "bind" or "license" some other constituent in the utterance. They're Operators, and have logical superpowers. Plus, they practically ooze ambiguity.

Comment: Leaving aside the free choice sense of "any", it is a polarity-sensitive determinative having a negative orientation, cf. "We haven't got any milk", but not *"We have got any milk". The free choice "any", as in "Any policeman will be able to tell you" is not of course polarity-sensitive.

Comment: @JohnLawler Suppose I say *He just selected any book on the shelf that appeared suitable.* There is no modal, and it is a single event.

Comment: And equally to @Colin Fine - how about *Do you have any book by Hemingway?*

Comment: @WS2: I find _Do you have any book by Hemingway_ marginally acceptable, and strongly tending to the "free choice" meaning.

Comment: @WS2: The _select_ sentence doesn't work without the relative clause. As for Hemingway, questions are natural negative contexts and the _any_ is the usual NPI _any_, as in _I don't have any books by Hemingway_.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the non-proportional "Do you have any book by Hemingway?" The non-proportional examples I usually cite are "I haven't got any job lined up for you today, I'm afraid", and the interrogative version "Do you have any job lined up for me today?" “Any” is of course an NPI in those examples.

Answer (score 1):

From § 2.54, CoGEL, "*any*", as a determiner, is used in the so-called *non-assertive* grammatical contexts. It can be found at § 5.14, Type (b) (ii) that it is the non-assertive central determiner of *plural count nouns* and *noncount nouns*  (of a type called called  quantifiers, § 5.23). Therefore, it is not considered acceptable to use it with *singular count nouns*. The meaning of any in this case is the counterpart of "some" (unstressed "some", which should be /səm/. In this context "*any*" is not stressed either.

*Count*

- They had some marbles in their pockets.
- Did they have any marble**s** in their pockets?

*Noncount*

- He drinks some soda with his meals.
- Does he drink any soda with his meals?
- Doesn't he drink any soda with his meals?

However, from § 6.61 we see that "*any*" occurs with a different meaning in assertive territory. This meaning is "*it doesn't matter which/what/who*". While the word is still a determiner, it is not now a *quantifier* and it is stressed.

*Examples from CoGEL*

- He will eat any kind of vegetable.
- Any dog might bite a child if teased.
- Any offer would be better than this.

This does not mean that it does not occur with this meaning in non-assertive territory.

- Did he tell you to read any book on the subject? No, not any, but only that one which has been recommended by the teacher. (user LPH's example)

This is the explanation for the occurrence of both plural and singular.